# "Unexpected end of input" - Code academy rock paper scissors

Tags: javascript, function

I'm new here and started trying to learn coding with Code Academy. I've been doing ok so far, getting the hang of things. However, I hit a little wall on their "Rock, Paper, Scissors" function task, at step 6.

Here's my code:

```
var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
if (choice1 === choice2) {
return "The result is a tie!";
}

else if (choice1 === "rock") {

if (choice2 ==="scissors") {
    return "Rock wins";
}
else {
    return "Paper wins";
}
}
```

for some reason, I keep getting an "Unexpected end of input" error, even though I did it exactly as said in the exercise. It doesn't point to the exact location of the error so I'm a little lost.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the closing `}` for your function declaration:

```
var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
  if (choice1 === choice2) {
    return "The result is a tie!";
  }

  else if (choice1 === "rock") {

    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
      return "Rock wins";
    }
    else {
      return "Paper wins";
    }
  }
} // <--- Closing '}' for function
```